# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key in groupby()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I used groupby() and ffill() to fill NULL for the DataFrame as below. The code works in other Python environment, but it failed when I switch to another Python environment with error message as :"ValueError: Columns must be same length as key".

The DataFrame:

```
ID     Var1    Var2    Var3     Var4
 1      AA      BB      CC        DD
 1      AA      NULL    NULL      NULL
 1      NULL    BB      CE        NULL
 2      AB      ED      EE        FF
 2      AB      NULL    EH        FG
 2      NULL    EC      NULL      NULL
 3      EG      FH      HG        FJ
 3      NULL    NULL    HJ        FK
 3      ER      FH      NULL      NULL
```

I tried to use the code to fill first 3 variables:
`df[['ID','Var1','Var2','Var3']]=df[['ID','Var1','Var2','Var3']].groupby(['ID'], sort=False, as_index=False).ffill()`

```
ID     Var1    Var2    Var3     Var4
 1      AA      BB      CC        DD
 1      AA      BB      CC        NULL
 1      AA      BB      CE        NULL
 2      AB      ED      EE        FF
 2      AB      ED      EH        FG
 2      AB      EC      EH        NULL
 3      EG      FH      HG        FJ
 3      EG      FH      HJ        FK
 3      ER      FH      HJ        NULL
```

The error shows:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: `df[['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3']] = df[['ID', 'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3']].groupby('ID', sort=False).ffill()`

Comment: For future reference, you can print out the results to see what you're getting vs what you've expected. `print(df[['ID','Var1','Var2','Var3']].groupby(['ID'], sort=False, as_index=False).ffill())`. You'd see that you only get `['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3']` back